# Trying to understand how importing modules (BioPython) in Sublime Text works

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext3, python-import, biopython

I am a beginner with coding in general. I have been enjoying using Sublime Text 3, but I've run into a problem that I can't figure out. I want to use the BioPython module in Sublime Text 3, but when I try to import the module, I get:

```
ImportError: No module named Bio
```

I downloaded BioPython as described on their website. When I go to Terminal and type:

```
python
>>> from Bio import SeqIO
```

It seems to work. I feel like it might have something to do with PATH, and Sublime Text not having the same PATH as Terminal, but I have almost no understanding of what this all means.

If you could walk me through what to do in Sublime Text to solve this issue, that would be great.

If you could point me to a resource that comprehensively teaches about PATH, that would be great.

---

I figured out how to solve this issue on my own and I thought I'd share what I did for any future denizens who come across this.

I learned that I am running into my problem because I have BioPython installed via Miniconda, and while my system is using Python via Miniconda, Sublime Text is still using my previous version of Python (I assume it's the Python that comes installed on Mac OS by default).

1. Open terminal and type `which python`
   Output: `/Users/my_username/miniconda2/bin/python`
2. In Sublime Text go to `Tools > Build System > New Build System...`
3. A blank build file will open, paste the following so that the file reads exactly this (the key here is that the path in the brackets following "cmd" is the path pointing to the Python you wish to use (the one that includes the module/s you wish to use).

```
{
    "cmd": ["/Users/my_username/miniconda2/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Save the file, it will be saved in `/Users/my_username/Library/ApplicationSupport/SublimeText3/Packages/User`

Now in Sublime Text 3 go to `Tools > Build System` and choose the build you just saved.

The end.

Comment: All Sublime does to run your program is execute an external program (by default, `python`); other than that it has no idea of what's going on with code you execute. As a first test, I would try running a simple program like `import sys; print(sys.version)` from the terminal and from Sublime and make sure they're both running the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Terminal output = 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:10:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] ............ Sublime Text output = 2.7.10 (default, Aug 17 2018, 19:45:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.0.42)]

Comment: That points to Sublime executing a different version of Python than you're using in the console. Have you set up a custom `sublime-build` file? The one that ships with  Sublime executes `python`

Comment: No, I have no idea what that is... Would you mind explaining how to do that and what I should write in this custom file?

Comment: What command are you executing in the terminal when this works?

Comment: Just `python` and then `>>>import pandas as pd`, and it does not throw an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191133/discussion-between-ddrsee-and-odatnurd).